# DB2 "activate database" command not working on the second instance

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a script to activate all DB2 databases under `db2inst1` and `db2inst2` profiles

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source rmdb/db2inst2/sqllib/db2profile

DB=("CIBWFDB" "CREDITDB" "RMDB" "ARCHIVO" "BRANCHES" "MEDB" "BPMARC" "PDWDB")

for d in "${DB[@]}"
do
rmdb/db2inst2/sqllib/bin/db2 activate db "$d"

done

libdb/db2inst2/sqllib/bin/db2 activate db ICMNLSDB
```

The script is placed under the `/rmdb/db2inst2` path and it's working fine for all the databases under `db2inst2` while for the database under `db2inst1` it gives the below error:

> SQL1092N "DB2INST2" does not have the authority to perform the
>   requested command or operation.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could solve the problem by making sure that the `db2inst2` ID has sufficient privileges for the `db2inst1` instance, it would be less confusing to use a different script for each instance and run the script as each instance owner.

Answer (score 0):

Following what Ian tells you, a dynamic script could be more interesting:

activateDBs:

```
INST_USER=$1
source ~${INST_USER}/sqllib/db2profile
for i in $(db2 list db directory | awk '/Database name/ {print $4}') ; do
  db2 activate db to $i
done
```

You call this script by issuing the following, from a user session that has privileges in both instances (sysmaint, sysctrl or sysadm):

```
activateDBs db2inst1
activateDBs db2inst2
```

References:

Activate - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002038.html